# how to we access objects with array?

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have a dump of data :

```
var_dump($steps);
```

and results are :

```
object(Drupal\form\Manager\StepManager)#490 (1) {
      ["steps":protected]=>
      array(1) {
        [1]=>
        object(Drupal\form\Step\StepOne)#494 (2) {
          ["step":protected]=>
          int(4)
          ["values":protected]=>
          array(1) {
            ["key"]=>
            string(3) "123"
          }
        }
```

but I tried using :

$steps[1]->values->key but its having an error, its not available directly?

where did I miss?

Comment: _"its not available directly?"_ - no, it isn't - that's what the `protected` in `["steps":protected]` is telling you. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php: _"Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class itself and by inheriting and parent classes."_ You need to go and see what getter method this StepManager object provides, to get access to this array. And then the same for the properties of StepOne, which are also protected.

Comment: yes I mean I know its protected, I mean there is not direct way of pulling it like using the -> something like that

Comment: No of course there is not, because that would be in total violation of what protected is supposed to do in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Your $steps array with in a object of **Drupal\form\Manager\StepManager**
and you accessed **key** from **values** object but your output shows you have a **values** array not object.

```
array(1) {
            ["key"]=>
            string(3) "123"
          }
```

So try this in **var_dump()** I think its worked

```
var_dump($steps->steps[1]->values["key"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The index to the first item – and only item in your case – is 0, and not 1. So this should work:

```
$steps[0]->...
```

The number 1 in the var_dump shows the size of the array:

```
["steps":protected]=>
      array(1) {  // This array contains one item
```